# Indexing Dataframe

Tags: pandas, indexing

I am getting SettingWithCopyWarning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

Here is my dataframe(Capacity):

```
                            A            B             C            D           E
2020-01-01 00:00:00       4.0           66            15          3.8         3.2
2020-01-01 01:00:00       4.0           66            15          3.8         3.2
2020-01-01 02:00:00       4.0           66            15          3.8         3.2
.
.
.
2020-03-23 22:00:00       4.0           66            15          3.8         3.2
2020-03-23 23:00:00       4.0           66            15          3.8         3.2
```

I want to change specific values which belongs to column A, based on date. I mean, if index's month is 3 and more than 3, change value 15 to 20.40.

```
Capacity['A'][(Capacity.index.month >= 3)] = 20.40
```

How can I write this line to avoid getting a warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for set values of `DataFrame`, not `Series`:

```
Capacity.loc[(Capacity.index.month >= 3), 'A'] = 20.40
```

More information in [`evaluation order matters`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters).